# Slider max value is number of items in my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slider, material-ui

I'm building a Material UI Slider. I'd like the max value of my slider to be according to the number of items in an array of options.

```
['Answer1', 'Answer2', 'Answer3', 'Answer4'];
```

In this case I have 4, but in some other case there might be 3 or 5 etc.
So in my Slider:

```
<Slider
 classes={{ container: classes.slider }}
 value={value}
 min={1}
 max={4}
 onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Here the max should be however many items are in my array (not just 4).
I guess I can do somehow myArray.length? And how can I implement that in my React component?

Comment: think about how you would use array.length to solve this.

Comment: const sliderValues = ['Answer1', 'Answer2', 'Answer3', 'Answer4'];

min{1} and max={sliderValues.length}, something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add there your array `.length` property, it will show number of items in your array

```
<Slider
 classes={{ container: classes.slider }}
 value={value}
 min={1}
 max={yourArray.length}
 onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```